# Induction problem with sum to n-1

Tags: induction

I am having trouble solving this induction problem because when I do the last step proving P(n+1), I do not know what exactly I need to substitute. Note that in the expression below k is a positive integer number.
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2ki+n-1 = {(k+1)(n-1)(n)}$

Comment: so the formula in your question describes $P(n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let ,
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(2ki+(n-1))$$
Now,
$$S_1=0$$
And 
$$(k+1)(1-1)(1)=0$$
The formula is true for $n=1$,$$$$$$$$

> Now ,
>   $$S_n=\color{red}{(n-1)}+\color{blue}{(2k+n-1)}+\color{green}{(6k+n-1)}+\cdots+(2k(n-1)+n-1)$$$$$$
>   $$S_{n+1}=\color{red}{(n)}+\color{blue}{(2k+n)}+\color{green}{(6k+n)}+\cdots+(2k(n)+n)$$$$$$
>   $$S_{n+1}-S_n=\color{red}{1}+\color{blue}{1}+\color{green}{1}+\cdots\text{n times}\cdots+1+(2kn+n)$$$$$$
>   $$S_{n+1}-S_n=n+(2kn+n)$$$$$$
>   $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{S_{n+1}-S_n=2(k+1)n}$$

If $S_n=(k+1)(n-1)n$
$$S_{n+1}=(k+1)n(n+1)$$
$$S_{n+1}-S_n=(k+1)(n)(n+1-n+1)$$
$$S_{n+1}-S_n=2(k+1)n$$
Which is also true,

Hence....